# Migration command error

Tags: 8, migrations, console

On Drupal 8.0.5, I have created a d6_migration module with the following dependencies.

```
  dependencies:
    - migrate_drupal
```

I activated my custom module, and I ran `drupal migrate:debug` which is returns me the following error:

> Missing module dependency "migrate" is not installed. Try
>    module:install to install it.

The Migrate and the Migrate Drupal modules are activated; `drupal module:install migrate` doesn't fix the problem.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: By _activated_, do you mean they are enabled?

Comment: i meant enabled yes